# Calling an exe file from web application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an exe file of a console application that takes parameter as:

> A.exe --i=123 --o=abc

The out is a generic tsv file created at a predefined output folder.

For some reason I need to develop a web application which can call A.exe (such that input parameters are passed as request parameters) and return the content of the file as a web response.

Something like:

www.myserver.com/A?i=123?o=abc

Can someone suggests few pointers to get started?

Answer (score 2):

You can try using Process as follows,

```
Process proc = new Process(); 
proc.EnableRaisingEvents = false; 
proc.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(exePath, @"A.exe");
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format(@"-i = ""{0}"" -o = ""{1}""", "123", "abc");
proc.Start()
```

Note : Set proper permission to the application pool to run this application.

Comment: Thanks. I got that but my point is how will I get the input parameters from the web request: www.myserver.com/A?i=123?o=abc

Comment: Put that in your question! From reading it I could only figure out that you have problem calling exe and getting it's output.

Comment: You can make use of Request.QueryString() Method in ASP.NET C#. CHeck the MSDN

Answer (score -1):

Make a dll of your exe and call it from asp.net handler .ashx 
It is a better option.

Comment: Hello, making a dll of exe how can we start a code of whole class file or if there is any background thread which is started from it then how can we close it?